# Python Tkinter: AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Tags: python, tkinter

Edit: when I use `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)` instead of `file=resize_image` nothing is displayed on my canvas.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s2dV.jpg).

I am creating an image viewer that is split into four frames with each of which displaying an image separately. Currently, I commented-out 3 out of four frames to focus on fixing the exceptions first.
I am trying to display an image inside a canvas, the latter being embedded inside `frame_1` on the top-left corner of the screen. Whenever I run my code I get the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/EM/Desktop/Scripts/gui/slideshow_model/slide_show_class.py", line 67, in <module>
    slideshow_model.show_image(img1)
  File "c:/Users/EM/Desktop/Scripts/gui/slideshow_model/slide_show_class.py", line 55, in show_image
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=resize_image)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 89, in __init__
    image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 58, in _get_image_from_kw
    return Image.open(source)
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2852, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x0000017EAD432D08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Here is my class:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()


class SlideshowModel():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = root
        master.title('Basic Image Viewer')
        root.iconbitmap('../img/favicon.ico')
        root.state('zoomed')
        s_w = int(root.winfo_screenwidth())
        s_h = int(root.winfo_screenheight())
        self.grid_w = s_w // 2
        self.grid_h = s_h // 2
        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(master, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0)
        self.frame_1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.can = tk.Canvas(
            self.frame_1, width=(self.grid_w - 50), height=(self.grid_h - 50), bg="red")
        self.can.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame_2 = tk.Frame(master, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_2.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.frame_3 = tk.Frame(master, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_3.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.frame_4 = tk.Frame(master, height=self.grid_h,
                                width=self.grid_w, bd=0, bg="black")
        self.frame_4.grid(column=1, row=1)


    # should return the image object
    def resize_image(self, img_path):
        image = Image.open(img_path)
        w_coeff = image.width / self.grid_w
        h_coeff = image.height / self.grid_h
        w_coeff = 1 / w_coeff if w_coeff > 1 else w_coeff
        h_coeff = 1 / h_coeff if h_coeff > 1 else h_coeff
        # pick the smallest coeff to get the image as small
        # as should be
        coeff = min(w_coeff, h_coeff)
        image = image.resize(
            (int(image.width * coeff), int(image.height * coeff)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return image

    # this function should show returned image
    # takes: image object, master frame
    def show_image(self, resize_image):
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)
        # label = tk.Label(frame_x, image=image, bd=0)
        self.can.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor='nw')


slideshow_model = SlideshowModel(root)

img1 = slideshow_model.resize_image('../img/sample.jpg')

slideshow_model.show_image(img1)

root.mainloop()
```

What am I missing?
Update: Now the window opens with no exceptions, but the image is **still not displayed**, I colored the `canvas` with color red and reduced its width and height by 50px to be able to differentiate it from the frame, the latter being colored (grey/white).

Comment: `resize_image` is not a file, but an image object. So `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=resize_image)` should probably be `ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)`

Comment: @Wups I edited my post. Actually, I used `file=...` instead of image object directly because I found it on another thread, now that I took it off, the exception does not appear but my image is not displayed either.

Comment: Change `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=resize_image)` to `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)` and also you forgot to call `pack()` or `grid()` on `self.can`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you for pointing out the `can.grid()` I forgot that, but still, the image is not displayed. check here: https://imgur.com/1OZyjpv

Comment: I think it has samething to do with image object being garbage collected, I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the photo image somewhere.

Comment: Change `image` to `self.image` in `show_image()`.

Comment: @acw1668 doesn't work :/

Comment: Update what you have changed in your posted code.

Comment: @acw1668 I just updated my code snippet.

Comment: @acw1668 @Wups I found the problem, the `image` object is being garbage collected, I had to prefix it with `self.` in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my `image = Image.open(...)` was being garbage collected, so I had to add `self.` so it is not destroyed. See code snippet below:

```
    def resize_image(self, img_path):
        self.image = Image.open(img_path)
        w_coeff = self.image.width / self.grid_w
        h_coeff = self.image.height / self.grid_h
        w_coeff = 1 / w_coeff if w_coeff > 1 else w_coeff
        h_coeff = 1 / h_coeff if h_coeff > 1 else h_coeff
        # pick the smallest coeff to get the image as small
        # as should be
        coeff = min(w_coeff, h_coeff)
        self.image = self.image.resize(
            (int(self.image.width * coeff), int(self.image.height * coeff)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        return self.image

    def show_image(self, resize_image):
        self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resize_image)
        self.can.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image_tk, anchor='center')
```